# Unable to use Pillow (not a valid WIN32 error)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am having a problem with running `pillow` for python 3.4.2.

I tried installing Pillow using 3 different files:
 `Pillow-3.2.0.win-amd64-py3.4.exe, 
 Pillow-3.2.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl,
 Pillow-3.2.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl.`

Every time I try to import Image or tkimage I get the `not a valid win32 error` in shell. Also, the 2 wheel files said they were incompatible with my system when using pip to install so I had to extract the data and place manually.

I am running windows 10 64bit but when I request what platform I'm running with python it says windows 8! In my system info from control panel it says the correct information though.

Please help if anyone knows the solution!

Comment: Do you have the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Python installed? I have a 64-bit Windows 7 system, but only use 32-bit Python — so have always installed the Pillow-X.Y.Z.win32-pyU.V files. It looks like you're trying to install the version for 64-bit Python.

Comment: "the 2 wheel files said they were incompatible with my system when using pip to install so I had to extract the data and place manually." it sounds like doing it manually didn't actually help, maybe try to figure out why pip was trying to install an incompatible version?

Comment: I had the same problem with Python showing the wrong Windows version number after upgrading from 8.1 to Windows 10. Later, I switched back to 8.1 and upgraded again, and it worked. I think Python's getting the version number from some registry entry. I'm using `platform.version()`, the platfom module's here: `C:\PythonXX\Lib\platform.py`. The `version()` function gets the version information from xx which gets it from `win32_ver()` (it returns `('10', '10.0.10586', '', 'Multiprocessor Free')` on my machine). And yes, theres a registry path in it: `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`

Comment: and in `_get_real_winver()` a reference to the kernel and version dll. `sys.getwindowsversion()` does still return `sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=2, build=9200, platform=2, service_pack='')` which is the the old 8.1 AFAIK. I can't look where this function gets the version from (it's written in C, I don't have currently the Python source), but in the end, it's a bit weired.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I finally figured it out! I had a 32 bit and a 64 bit version of python installed. I had pillow installed to my 32 bit directory, so when python ran from 32 bit was why I got the win32 error. And when I ran python 64bit it said module not found. Uninstalled both and reinstalled the 64 bit to the normal install direc in C, reinstalled 64 bit pillow and it worked!

After updating pip it was able to read the wheel files.